# Passing an argument to a function n times

Tags: rust, rust-macros

I'm experimenting with different patterns in Rust, and wanted to try to dynamically invoke one of several functions with similar signatures, but different numbers of arguments. For example:

```
fn foo(x: i32) -> i32 { x }
fn bar(x1: i32, x2: i32) -> i32 { x1 + x2 }
fn baz(x1: i32, x2: i32, x3: i32) -> i32 { x1 + x2 + x3 }
```

I'd like to be able to pass a value in for *all* the parameters to these methods, so that they could be called interchangeably - so if the input was `5` I'd like to be able to call `foo(5)`, `bar(5, 5)`, or `baz(5, 5, 5)`, and so on.

It seems like this would be best done by a macro or other syntax extension, but I'm not sure the best way to express it. What I have so far is just a brute-force enumeration of the cases, but this seems both tedious (to re-write the same expression for every case) and brittle (it doesn't support n+1 arguments):

```
// Takes a function and an expected number of args and returns a closure that
// takes exactly one arg and passes it n times to the given function.
macro_rules! expand {
    ($func:ident, 0) => { Box::new(|_n: i32| $func()) };
    ($func:ident, 1) => { Box::new(|n: i32| $func(n)) };
    ($func:ident, 2) => { Box::new(|n: i32| $func(n, n)) };
    ($func:ident, 3) => { Box::new(|n: i32| $func(n, n, n)) };
}
```

I came across [this pattern](http://danielkeep.github.io/tlborm/book/pat-push-down-accumulation.html) which seems similar, but it still requires enumerating each case separately.

Is there a better approach that can more flexibly wrap a `fn(X, ...)` as a function that takes exactly one `X`?

[Playground example](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=c85904d88833c87621c6d831425ae95a&version=stable)

Comment: I am not sure to understand your question (or your intent), but why do not you give a slice or an iterator to the function? For example: if your input is `let input = 5`, repeat the number: `let slice = iter::repeat(input).take(the_number_you_want).collect()` and feed it to your function.

Comment: @Boiethios the function signatures are fixed - I agree something like an iterator would be reasonable, but for my purposes here the functions need positional arguments. This MCVE is a toy example - my actual use case is more complex but this is the part I'm unsure about.

Comment: If you want a kind of overload polymorphism, the best is to create a struct with all your parameters and give it to the func as unique parameter; then you implement `From` trait for a bunch of tuples with all the combinations you want. Or you use the builder pattern that is very idiomatic in Rust. But if you cannot change the functions signatures, this does not work (and even, I wonder how one can help you). Maybe you should be more explicit in you question, because in current state, it *seems* too broad to be correctly answered.

Comment: @Boiethios I don't see how it's too broad - I'm looking for a better way to implement `expand!` such that all the cases don't have do be individually enumerated. I've intentionally tried to narrow the scope of the question.

Comment: A [compiler plugin](https://doc.rust-lang.org/1.12.0/book/compiler-plugins.html) might be the only way to achieve this.

Comment: @user4815162342 thanks, I may have to dive into that. I'd been trying to avoid it... :)

Answer (score 0):

[Here](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2015&gist=53341d9013bf5107d0182fd1eeb039d8)'s a function `expand` that can simply be called with the name of your function, and returns the "expanded" version. I.e. you can use it like this:

```
fn main() {
    let state = 15;
    let vs: Vec<Box<dyn Fn(i32) -> i32>> = vec![
        expand(foo),
        expand(bar),
        expand(baz),
        expand(|x| x+1), // with lambdas
        expand(move |x| x+state), // with stateful lambdas
    ];
    for f in &vs {
        println!("{:?}", f(1));
    }
}

fn foo(x: i32) -> i32 { x }
fn bar(x1: i32, x2: i32) -> i32 { x1 + x2 }
fn baz(x1: i32, x2: i32, x3: i32) -> i32 { x1 + x2 + x3 }
```

It works by defining a trait `TExpand` that is implemented for function types. As far as I can see, I must make the `impl`s distinct (thus the `TplDummy` parameter).

```
trait TExpand<T, R, TplDummy> {
    fn call(&self, t: T) -> R;
}
macro_rules! ignore_ident{
    ($id:ident, $($t:tt)*) => {$($t)*};
}
macro_rules! impl_expand{
    () => {};
    ($t0:ident $($t:ident)*) => {
        impl_expand!($($t)*);
        impl<T: Copy, R, F:Fn($(ignore_ident!($t, T),)*)->R> TExpand<T, R, ($(ignore_ident!($t, T),)*)> for F {
            #[allow(unused_variables)] // for nullary function
            fn call(&self, t: T) -> R {
                (self)($(ignore_ident!($t, t),)*)
            }
        }
    }
}
impl_expand!(t0 t1 t2 t3);

fn expand<TplDummy, T, R, F:TExpand<T, R, TplDummy>+'static>(f: F) -> Box<dyn Fn(T)->R> {
    Box::new(move |t| f.call(t))
}
```

You can expand the range of the argument counts by adjusting the call to `impl_expand`.